# How to perform a segue from a pushed vc that has the segue defined in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Here is the thing: my storyboard as a SettingViewController (after named SVC) and a StationsViewcontroller from which the latter is wired to a details view controller by the "openDetails" segue.

For practical reasons, my SVC can push several levels of specifics settings view controllers, which I did not defined in the storyboard.

At one point, one of those vc pushes the StationsViewController, which then can issue a performSegue to the detail: unfortunately, I get the "openDetails" segue is not defined.

What should I do to fix the issue?

--

The code has nothing peculiar, in the SettingsViewController, I push others VC, including the StationsViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Gracefully remove the selection
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    guard let section = MainSections(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return }

    switch section {
    case .stations:
        let vc = StationsViewController()
        // Do no segue at dismiss
        vc.onlyDismiss = true
        vc.didDismiss = {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        push(vc, hideNavigation: true)

        // Blah blah
```

And in the StationsViewController where I want to get to the details vc, I  perform the segue:

```
func openPoiDetails(_ gs: GasStation) {

    poiDetails = gs

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "poiDetails", sender: nil)

    // Blah blah
```

The storyboard is as follows, and we can see the StationsViewController on the left is wired to the details vc via the "openDetails" segue:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `StationsViewController` was just created from its initializer and the `storyboard` knows nothing about it.  Therefore, you can't use the segue.  Instead, you need to ask the `storyboard` to instantiate the `StationsViewController`:

Replace:

```
let vc = StationsViewController()
```

with:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StationsViewController") as! StationsViewController
```

Make sure you set the `"StationsViewController"` as the **Storyboard ID** in the *Identify Inspector* in Xcode.

Comment:  I find myself ridiculous, I should stop working overnight lol. Thanks.